# Perform Sorting on data stored as the key value pair on the ignite distributed cache

Tags: sorting, ignite

I want to perform sorting on data stored as the key-value pair in apache distributed cache. Is there any API available by default to perform sorting?
Moreover, if I write my own sorting logic, will it be a performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` with SQL, but you have to be careful to not run out of memory, since all entries in the affected caches will be brought to heap.

If you sort on columns that have a proper SQL index on them, index will be used instead of pulling all rows to heap. Using `LIMIT` or [`lazy=true`](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging#result-set-lazy-load) is adviced in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually  "you have to be careful to not run out of memory"  is the main concern. could you please guide me on that.

Comment: Your data set should fit in RAM for sorting. If it does not, use SQL index. I will update answer.